# Proof language meaning: "the only objects for which condition 1 holds are those for which condition 2 holds"

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

I'm reviewing my basic linear algebra/calculus, and encountered this statement: "the only functions $L : R → R$ which are linear are those of the
form $L(x) = ax$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$".  (on page 2 of [this document](http://cfsv.synechism.org/c1/sec15.pdf))

Based on the context I interpret this as "the functions $L : R → R$ which are linear are *precisely* those of the form $L(x) = ax$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$". Is this correct?

More generally, can I take "the only objects for which condition 1 holds are those for which condition 2 holds" to mean equivalence between the 2 conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, *no*. For example: "The only birds which are swans are those with long necks." This is a true statement - only birds with long necks can be swans, because swans have long necks - but as there are plenty of birds with long necks that are *not* swans, like ostriches, equivalence does not hold.

"The only objects for which condition 1 holds are those for which condition 2 holds" simply means that if an object meets condition 1, then it must *also* meet condition 2. Another way of saying that is that the set of objects meeting condition 1 is a (possibly proper) subset of the set of objects meeting condition 2.

In this particular case, however, your analysis is correct - but only because functions of the form $L(x) = ax$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ are obviously linear, so we get the other direction for free. This sort of interpretation will often work, always for the same reason - this phrasing is not usually used unless condition 2 obviously implies condition 1, in which case we do get equivalence. But you should always be very careful about applying this reasoning.